# When the full SDK will be available?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I would be very interested to know when the full Ubuntu SDK is going to be released. Is there any preliminary schedule planned that could be published or is it still way too early stage? Or is there any other way to build some working version of Ubuntu part for Touch while waiting for the SDK? Like getting bits and pieces from here and there..?

Comment: The exact release schedule for the SDK isn't known at this time.  Any updates to the schedule would be release through the normal channels.

Comment: This I was afraid of that I cannot get any schedule :) Anyway, thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 3):

In summary, we're planning a beta for July and the 1.0 release in October.